# Can't log into Vultre VPS Ubuntu with ssh RSA puTTY public key on windows

Tags: ssh, putty, vps

I was not able to log into VPS (Vulture) with my puTTY public key.

I generated the public and private key, but got an error "Server refused our keys".

AN UPDATE A YEAR LATER:

just use bash for windows and the program called "ssh-keygen", which is available in bash for windows.

download here:
https://gitforwindows.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that

1. You need to generate your public keys with putty. (all default settings)
2. Then you need to load your private key into the putty gen
3. And only then you will get the public key on screen in the putty software, that you can copy into your VPS.
4. Then you can browse and load your private kay under Putty (ssh sofware) -> Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> Authentication Parameters -> Browse -> find and select your generated private key.

So basically when you generate your keys with puTTY you don't even need to save your public key.

And sometimes, for example, for MySql Workbench you need to make the unforced openSSl key version. Specifically unforced. So I suggest make all the possible permutations of those keys and try them all out.. if something doesn't work regarding keys.

Answer (score 0):

And if you are on windows, but wan to connect to your VPS using bash, then

1. You need to load your private key in the puTTYgen sofware.. the one you generated
2. You need to press on Conversions > Export OpenSSH format (force ...) > save it
3. Open bash terminal
4. And wrtie these lines.. 

   `` $ eval `ssh-agent -s`  # start ssh agent
   $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa  # delete ssh key ``

   - if you write ~ in front of a path in something-linux, that takes you to your windows User directory
   - the command ~/.shh/id_rsa assumes that in your windwos User directory you have a folder named ".ssh" in which there is a file named "id_rsa" with no extension
   - you need to name the file id_rsa, because that's the default name bash will search for